# How am i supposed to use getchar()

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{       
    int age;
    std::cout << "how old are you ?";
    std::cin >> age;
    std::cout << "you are " << age << "\n";

    printf("Press ENTER key to continue \n");
    getchar();
    printf("this is dumb");
}
```

this is my code, every time I run it, it will always skip the getchar() input and just execute whatever is next. I feel really dumb lol

Comment: Probably `getchar()` receives the `\n` symbol that you input after `age`? Run `std::getline` (or something similar) before that to skip until the end of line.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction?r=Saves_AllUserSaves

Comment: Also, may I suggest using `std::cin.get()` rather than `getchar()` as you're already using the `iostream` `cin` and `cout` objects. Using the C-style functions might be a bit counter-intuitive if you're not familiar with how they interact with C++'s `iostream`.

Comment: *" it will always skip the `getchar()`"* -- skipping statements is rather unlikely (in the absence of `if` or other branching logic). It would be better to think of this as "no noticeable effect" then ask yourself "how can I make it have a noticeable effect?" *In this case, you could check the value returned by `getchar()` -- `auto c = getchar(); std::cout << "This is " << c << ". Dumb?\n";`*

Comment: You can mix `iostream` and `cstdio` I/O if you like, it is perfectly "legal", but the general consensus is pick one or the other.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you're experiencing is due to the behavior of the [*FormattedInputFunction*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/FormattedInputFunction) [`operator>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt). When you input a value using `std::cin >> age;`, the newline character (`\n`) from hitting Enter remains in the input buffer. The subsequent getchar() call then reads this newline character, causing it to appear as though it's being skipped.

To resolve this, you can flush the newline out of the buffer before calling `getchar()`. One way to do this is by using `std::cin.ignore()`. This function discards characters in the input buffer up to a specified delimiter, which in this case can be the newline character (`'\n'`):

```cpp
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

You can modify your code as follows:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    int age;
    std::cout << "how old are you ?";
    std::cin >> age;
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    std::cout << "you are " << age << "\n";
    printf("Press ENTER key to continue \n");
    getchar();
    printf("this is dumb");
}
```

`std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` is used to discard all characters in the input buffer until a newline character is found, effectively flushing the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion, here is some *pause* code without crossing the streams:

```
std::cout << "\nPaused.  Press Enter to continue.\n";
std::cin.ignore(1000000, '\n');
```

The the `ignore` method will wait until the quantity of characters is passed (the first parameter) or the second parameter is encountered.  Some people will propose using the maximum integer value.  I just use some absurdly large number that is unlikely to occur. :-)

Comment: A better (ie, more accurate) way to use `ignore()` is `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` Don't make assumptions about the terminal width. Using an actual width will stop reading when that width is reached (however unlikely it is, the terminal *might* be that large!) whereas using `std::streamsize` will disable the width checking altogether and just read forever until `'\n'` is encountered.

Answer (score -2):

I have modified your code and tested it.

The first `getchar()` received `'\n'`, you only need to add one more `getchar()` to achieve your goal.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    {
        int age;
        std::cout << "how old are you ?";
        std::cin >> age;
        std::cout << "you are " << age << "\n";
    }
    printf("Press ENTER key to continue \n");
    char i = getchar();
    std::cout << "||" << i << "||" << std::endl;
    getchar();
    printf("this is dumb");
}
```

Comment: This breaks if they enter e.g. a space after the number.